# Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have tried to insert the value in db in my mocha test i am getting this error i tried few of the following ways but nothing work out.

```
var assert=require('chai').assert;
const user=require('../model/user')
```

i tried both way

```
describe('insertDataLasone',()=>{
    it('should save the value ',(done)=>{
        var User = new user({fname:'test'});
        User.save().then(done=>{
            done()
        }).catch(done=>done())
    })
})

describe('User', function() {
    describe('#save()', function() {
        // this.timeout(5000)
      it('should save without error', function(done) {          
        var User5 = new user({fname:'test'});
        User5.save(function(done) {
          if (err) done(err);
          else setTimeout(done,3000);
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Don't you think in both the ways you are shadowing the actual function name and calling your callback function and not the actual `done`?

Comment: I tried that way also still  getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when `done()` is not called in a test. Make sure you are calling `done()`.

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
const User = require('../model/user');

describe('insertDataLasone', () => {
  it('should save the value ', done => {
      var user = new User({ fname: 'test' });
      user.save().then(() => {
        done();
      })
      .catch(done); // mocha done accepts Error instance
  });
});
```

or

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
const User = require('../model/user');

describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user5 = new User({ fname: 'test' });
      user5.save(function(err) {
        if (err) done(err);
        else done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Read https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code carefully